# Using prototype, TypeError: task1.completed is not a function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, this, javascript-objects, prototypejs

I follow a JS Design pattern tutorial which explain using prototype to prevent we new 'this' every time when we new an object. However, when I run the code as below, it pop up the error as below. I followed the tutorial code completely, that's why I don't understand why on the tutorial it has no error show up.

> TypeError: task1.completed is not a function

```
    var Task = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.completed = false;

    }

    Task.prototype.completed = function () {
        console.log('completing task: ' + this.name);
        this.completed = true;
    }


    Task.prototype.save = function () {
        console.log('saving task: ' + this.name);
    }

    var task1 = new Task('create a demo for constructors');
    var task2 = new Task('create a demo for modules');
    var task3 = new Task('create a demo for singletons');
    var task4 = new Task('create a demo for prototypes');

    task1.completed();
    task2.save();
    task3.save();
    task4.save();
```

My another question is, as the tutorial mentioned, we should always use this way to implement class, but why I haven't seen this pattern in many code? I only see the usage of prototype in implementing JS built in methonds, eg. Object.prototype.toString(). But in our real life, I haven't seen it a lot. Is just I'm not familiar JS code?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the inner instance variable or the function to something else. You are getting a namespace clash. When you write:

```
Task.prototype.completed
```

This is similar to writing

```
this.completed = ...
```

Except the prototype is used in all newly created Task objects after the declaration. However, you already defined an instance variable called `this.completed`.

Thus if you name the inner instance variable to `this._completed` or something along these lines, your code will run as you expect.

Comment: I see, but when I use this._name, it seems, the prototype doesn't actually get property value. So now it printed out as                                                    
completing task: undefined
saving task: undefined
saving task: undefined
saving task: undefined                                                                                                         I guess I still don't understand how the prototype work, as my understanding is the instance task1, task2, task3, task4 all point to Task.prototype, but seems the prototype couldn't get the parameter value of the instances?